# mysql error help... while running rake db:setup RAILS_ENV="production"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am diligently trying to get mysql up and running for my first rails app ever. 
I keep getting the following error when running rake db:setup RAILS_ENV="production":

```
rake aborted!
dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9):     Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dyl Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
Reason: image not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2    /mysql2.bundle
/Users/chris/rails_projects/sienab/Rakefile:4
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I am running snow leopard, mysql 5.5, gem mysql2, rails 3.

Any help is great.  many thanks.

database.yml below
        # SQLite version 3.x
        #   gem install sqlite3
        development:
          adapter: sqlite3
          database: db/development.sqlite3
          pool: 5
          timeout: 5000

```
    # Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
    # re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
    # Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
    test:
      adapter: sqlite3
      database: db/test.sqlite3
      pool: 5
      timeout: 5000

    production:
      adapter: mysql2
      encoding: utf8
      reconnect: false
      database: sienab_production
      pool: 5
      username: username
      password: password
      host: localhost
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `bundle exec` to the beginning of the command so you're running it in the bundled gem environment?

Comment: does this make a difference: `rake db:setup RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: otherwise, show your `database.yml`file

Comment: thanks ... suggestion does not make difference.  database.yml is added.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to install the mysql2 libs:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev libmysqlclient16
```

Also, I suggest you use `gem 'mysql2','0.2.7'` in your Gemfile if you're using Rails 3.0.x.
Don't forget to run `bundle install` after making this change.